# How to get methods and values used in an IQueryable?

Tags: c#, iqueryable

I'm trying to parse an `IQueryable` and I want to get the methods and parameters called on the `IQueryable`.

e.g.

```
var query = Queryable.Skip(10).Take(100);

bool hasCalledSkipMethod = HasSkipMethod(query);
var skipValue = GetSkipMethodParameterValueSomeHow(query);

bool hasCalledTakeMethod = HasTakeMethod(query);
var takeValue = GetTakeMethodParameterValueSomeHow(query);
```

Or some generic method that receives an `IQueryable` and returns all the methods name and parameters.

How can I get the methods and it's parameters that was applied in an `IQueryable`?

Comment: can you further explain what,for example, `GetSkipMethodSomeHow` needs to do?

Comment: @styx I just edited the method name. It just need to check if it's using that method (in this case, if the method `Skip` was called)

Comment: probably you have to check the content of the Expression Tree generated by your lambda. Here a little explanation from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/expression-trees-interpreting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it is the best possible approach, but it might work for what you want or at least guide you in the right direction.

Each `IQueryable` has an [`Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) that represents the query to be executed as a tree data structure where each node is in itself also an `Expression`. So whenever you do `.Take(int)` in a `IQueryable` what's happening behind the scenes is that a new Node of type [`MethodCallExpression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression?view=net-5.0) for the method `Take(int)` is added to the Expression tree of that `IQueryable`.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.take?view=net-5.0#remarks):

> The Take(IQueryable, Int32) method generates a MethodCallExpression that represents calling Take(IQueryable, Int32) itself as a constructed generic method. It then passes the MethodCallExpression to the CreateQuery(Expression) method of the IQueryProvider represented by the Provider property of the source parameter.

Therefore, what you want to do is to *traverse* (visit each node in the tree) and see if there is any Node of type [`MethodCallExpression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression?view=net-5.0) where the method name of the Expression is, in this case, `"Take"`.

To traverse the expression tree you can create an [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor?view=net-5.0) that overrides the method [`VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.visitmethodcall?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Expressions_ExpressionVisitor_VisitMethodCall_System_Linq_Expressions_MethodCallExpression_). This custom visitor could accept a method's name to be checked as a constructor parameter and, when visiting the nodes, store in an internal property if the method name was found or not.

Once you have your custom visitor, you could call the [`Visit(Expression)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.visit?view=net-5.0) where expression will be [`queryable.Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable?view=net-5.0#properties).

Here is a gist of it.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        IQueryable<int> queryable = new []{ 78, 92, 100, 37, 81 }
            .AsQueryable()
            .Skip(1)
            .Take(2);

        Expression expression = queryable.Expression;
        
        var hasTakeMethodVisitor = new HasMethodVisitor("Take");
        var hasSkipMethodVisitor = new HasMethodVisitor("Skip");
        var hasWhereMethodVisitor = new HasMethodVisitor("Where");
        
        hasTakeMethodVisitor.Visit(expression);
        hasSkipMethodVisitor.Visit(expression);
        hasWhereMethodVisitor.Visit(expression);
        
        System.Console.WriteLine("Has Take Method? {0}", hasTakeMethodVisitor.HasMethod);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Has Skip Method? {0}", hasSkipMethodVisitor.HasMethod);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Has Where Method? {0}", hasWhereMethodVisitor.HasMethod);
    }
    
    internal class HasMethodVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
        
        private readonly string _methodToFind;
        
        public HasMethodVisitor(string methodName) {
            _methodToFind = methodName;
        }
        
        public bool HasMethod { get; private set; }
        
        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node) {
            HasMethod |= node.Method.Name == _methodToFind;
        
            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Has Take Method? True
Has Skip Method? True
Has Where Method? False
```